# Как отключить heading для всех запросов firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть запрос на firebird с конкатенацией и использованием вложенных select и list(), это все пишется потом в файл. Вначале стоит команда SET HEADING OFF;

```
SET HEADING OFF;
SELECT DISTINCT '"' || REPLACE(TRIM(COALESCE(x.column, '')), '"', '""')
|| '"; "' || REPLACE(TRIM(COALESCE(x.column2, '')), '"', '""')
|| '"; "' || REPLACE(TRIM(COALESCE(list(DISTINCT x.column3, ','), '')), '"', '""')
|| '";'
FROM (
     SELECT ycolumn AS column, ycolumn1 AS column1, ycolumn2 AS column2, list(DISTINCT ycolumn3, ',') AS column3
FROM (
     SELECT d.column AS ycolumn, c.column1 AS ycolumn1, dc.column2 AS ycolumn2, ws.column3 AS ycolumn3
     FROM ...
     )y
     GROUP BY ycolumn, ycolumn1, ycolumn2
) x
GROUP BY x.column, x.column1, x.column3
;
```

Проблема в том, что не отключаются заголовки для вложенных SELECT и получается на выходе в файле такое:

```
==============================================================================
            0:218
==============================================================================
CONCATENATION:
"field"; "field1"; "field2"; "field3";
```

Подскажите, возможно ли отключить заголовки для такого запроса? Или придется вручную убирать?

Comment: Попробовал привести к VARCHAR то, что генерит list(), но не помогло.

Comment: 1) Какая версия firebird? 2) Что за клиентское приложение? 3) почему вы уверены, что видите заголовки вложенных запросов?